IntelliJ Http Client Body with XML
Goal: A POST request with the IntelliJ HTTP Client and SOAP XML body
Problem: Body Tag seems not to work with the XML.
I tried to make the following requests with the IntelliJ HTTP Client:
### CLient Init
POST http://localhost:8080/application/cxf/EmbeddedWebService
Accept: text/xml
Authorization: Bearer {{$auth.token("bearer")}}
Content-Type: text/xml
Body: <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://webservice.embedded.server.qa.company.com/"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><web:init><!--Optional:--><web:WebserviceSessionId><id>234567</id></web:WebserviceSessionId><!--Optional:--><web:WebserviceTaskId><id>34567z</id></web:WebserviceTaskId><!--Optional:--><web:InitContext><quoteId>1234567</quoteId><locale>de</locale><userId>2134567</userId><offline>false</offline><activated>false</activated><customData></customData><readOnly>false</readOnly></web:InitContext></web:init></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>


<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Error reading XMLStreamReader: Unexpected EOF in prolog&#xd;
                at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]
            </faultstring>
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Unfortunately, I keep getting error messages that it is not valid XML. My assumption here is that it cannot properly put the XML format into the body.
The application responds without any problems to a GET request.
### CLient HTTP Webserver
GET http://localhost:8080/application/cxf/EmbeddedWebService?wsdl
Authorization: Bearer {{$auth.token("bearer")}}

